# How to subtract symbolic value from list and get log value

Tags: python, list, numpy, logging, sympy

I have to subtract symbolic value from a list and get log value of that. This will return corresponding symbolic expressions as a list. That expression should be element vice operation.

I have tried this using numpy and sympy in different ways. But without using loops, I couldn't find a solution.

```py
import sympy as sp
u = sp.symbols('u', real=False)
a = [1, 2, 3, 5]
answer = sp.log(u - a)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Symbol' and 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want as an output is: `[log(u - 1), log(u - 2), log(u - 3), log(u - 5)]`

**With Loop:**

```
import sympy as sp
a = [1, 2, 3, 5]
[sp.log(u - x) for x in a]
```

**Without Loop:**

```
import sympy as sp
u = sp.symbols('u', real=False)
a = [1, 2, 3, 5]
answer = list(map(lambda x: sp.log(u - x), a))
answer
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the help.